# Gnuplot gprintf() doesn't work anymore on new computer

Tags: gnuplot

I worte a script for gnuplot in my university and took the data to my computer at home.
Here is the relevant code:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font 'Helvetica,20';
set encoding utf8;


do for[i=2:12] for[j in "3 4 6"]{

set autoscale x; 
set xr[-3:3];
set autoscale y;
set key right bottom;
set terminal postscript eps color ;
set termoption dash;


set xlabel "bla";
set ylabel "bla"; 

set output 'home/Plots/test-'.i.'-'.j.'.eps';

plot  'home/Daten/test-'.i.'-'.j.'.dat' with lines lw 4 title gprintf("homogen q=%.3f",(1/(j-1)-1/(10*(j-1)))/2);    }
```

The gprintf() doesnt work..it only gives me 0.00 but at the computer in my uni it does it right...help anyone :(

edit:
I found out that gnuplot rounds...when i type in

```
gprintf("homogen q=%.3f",j)
```

it gives me `q=3` for j=3.00

If i use:

```
gprintf("homogen q=%.3f",j/5)
```

it gives me `q=0.00`

it has to be a problem with gnuplot..because, as i said, on the other computer it worked :/

Comment: You probably have integer division, use `1.0` etc for the calculations

Comment: Thanks for the anwer :) I am quite new to gnuplot...what do you mean with 'use 1.0 etc.' ?

Comment: You were right...If i type 2/4 it is zero..if i type 2.0/4 it is 0.5... but the problem is, i can't do that for j as a variable...can i change it in the gnuplotsettings itself?

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

Use

```
... gprintf("homogen q=%.3f",(1.0/(j-1.0)-1.0/(10.0*(j-1.0)))/2.0)
```

The loop variables are integers by default and gnuplot is quite literal in its use of integer arithmetic, as you have already discovered...

#### Unrequested Advice

As a matter of style, I'd suggest to simplify the individual line's title to `q = ...` and use a descriptive plot title, e.g.,

`Response curves for different values of the specific energy "q"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did what you said and it worked properly! I still wonder though why it worked without the '.0' in the version of gnuplot in my university...